# How do i place a background image on tab window in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i wanted to know how to place a background image on Tkinter tab window i usually get an error.please help

Comment: we can't see your screen and we can't read in your mind. If you need help then put code an FULL error message in question.

Answer (score 0):

### Main Window:

```
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry('100x100')

C = Canvas(gui, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
filename = PhotoImage(file='example.png')
filename = filename.zoom(7)
filename = filename.subsample(18)
background_label = Label(gui, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
C.pack()

gui.mainloop
```

Or

#### New Tab Window:

```
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry('100x100')

def Tab():

    gui = Toplevel()
    gui.geometry('100x100')

    C = Canvas(gui, bg="blue", height=250, width=300)
    filename = PhotoImage(file='example.png')
    filename = filename.zoom(7)
    filename = filename.subsample(18)
    background_label = Label(gui, image=filename)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    C.pack()

Tab()

gui.mainloop()
```

You Also Need To Have Your Image In The Defined Directory.

Hope It Helps & Welcome To StackOverflow!